# Selecting smaller polygons first into a QGIS Web map

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, select, qgis2web

Here is my issue, I am having a QGIS Map with polygons, I edited the symbology in order to stack the smaller area ones first so they can be clicked first to open the pop up window in the web map later. The things is that in the QGIS Project works just fine, here an example:

[image]

But when I generate the web map using qgis2map, it appears that the smaller one is below the big one and it is impossible to click it to show up the pop up, here it is:

[image]

When selecting with the mouse:

[image]

So I am unable to select the polygon underneath and open its pop up.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting of qgis2web plans to do it with the current feature (with the above geometry).
The only way is to raise the layer that contains the small circles, however if your layers are mixed, i.e. they contain both small circles and large circles the only solution is to adopt a layerswitcher that allows you to move the layers up or down.
For example I use the Viglino layerswitcher https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/control/map.switcher.html
This allows you to move the levels up and down, so you will succeed in your intent.